# Is there a php function to match 3 consecutive lines on a file

Tags: php, bash, scripting

Anyone who can give advise, i'm looking for a php function or method to matching 3 consecutive lines on a file e.g

```
php is fun,
linux is interesting,
Windows is fun,
Ubuntu is ubuntu,
Perl is fun,
```

How can i match the below from the above text ?

```
linux is interesting,
Windows is fun,
Ubuntu is ubuntu,
```

At the moment i can match if its a single line .

Comment: Do you want to make sure that the below text exists in the string give above?

Comment: `file()` to put the values in to an array, then `explode()` your search string on comma, then  loop your search array  to find matches

Comment: "linux is interesting, Windows is fun, Ubuntu is ubuntu," is of course three lines. But, it is single string. Isn't it? Just use string compare function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be possible in three ways.

**Firstly** by using `regex` with `preg_match_all()`

```
$str = "php is fun, linux is interesting, Windows is fun, Ubuntu is ubuntu, Perl is fun,";
$res = preg_match_all("/(linux is interesting|Windows is fun|Ubuntu is ubuntu)/", $str);
if ($res)
    echo "Text is founded in string";
```

If you just need to know if any of the words is present, use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as above. If you need to match all the occurences of any of the words, use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and `|` pipe sign indicates `or`

**secondly** by using the `stripos()` which indicates if a string contains specific words or not and if contains it returns the starting position of the words.

```
print_r(stripos($str, "Windows is fun"))
```

**Thridly** if you are separating your string sentences with `,` delimiter then it can be possible by using `explode()` to convert string into *array* then match one by one with another *array*.

```
$str = "php is fun, linux is interesting, Windows is fun, Ubuntu is ubuntu, Perl is fun,";
$exp = explode(",", $str);

$match = array("linux is interesting", "Windows is fun", "Ubuntu is ubuntu");

foreach ($exp as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($match as $key_match => $value_match) {
        if ($value === $value_match) {
            echo "String match founded <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , the first method will work perfectly as i want to match the 3 exact 3 lines.